# Can't Get Detail of a Record/Row Generated uding Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, json, jquery, codeigniter-2

I'm using jquery and codeigniter and wrote code which produce result using .ajax json and display the result in a div called 'result-table'.
Then from the results, I want to performed another query using the same method to get detail info for each row (trigger by clicking on each row). The following code seems able to get the parameter (assetid), but it can't display the result again to the same div 'result-table'. In short I wanted to get detail info of individual rows that resulted from first AJAX query ..AJAX after AJAX..sorry for my english.

```
//this function - when user click on a row...it will perform another query using ajax json..and display the result in div id=result_table

$('#getassetinfo').live('click', function() {
 assetid=$(this).attr("id_hm");

$.ajax({

        url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/amx/get_asset_info_json/';?>'+ assetid,
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
                $('#result_table').append(output_string);
            } 
        }); // End of ajax call
```

});

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have errors here: If you have firebug , double check it on console panel

```
url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/amx/get_asset_info_json/';?>'+ assetid,
```

This should fix it:

```
url: '/index.php/amx/get_asset_info_json/'+ assetid,
```

Comment: still not working as I intended..no result display, yeah.. I'm using firebug ...no error it said OK..JSON generated but it is not display onto the DIV

Comment: if you the url returns you the json and if you want to display your result.. uncomment this `//$('#result_table').append(output_string);` ??

Comment: sorry...actually I'm not commented the line at the first place. It is still not working. I don't know, maybe, something to do with child parent thing in jquery, can somebody enlighten me.

Comment: are you sure you're having a json response? if not then your $('#getassetinfo').live('click', function() {}); or assetid=$(this).attr("id_hm") is not working, double check them.

Comment: no problem with that. I just changed  $('#result_table').append(output_string); to $('#result_table').html(output_string);..and it's work

Comment: lol, append should work also.. anyways case is solved. cheers!

Comment: no problem with that. I just changed  $('#result_table').append(output_string); to $('#result_table').html(output_string);..and it's work...the only thing i need to do the html formatting before return and encode it in json... I'm still learning jquery codeigniter..Thanks for your attention